# How to Export Google Search History

Tags: google-chrome

Looks like Google has stopped supporting "Download Searches" button as mentioned here: https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/6068625?hl=en . One option is to get history from Google Chrome using something like this https://gist.github.com/evidanary/d02d89c632530878163f256fe993d5a4 . But the history in Chrome is not complete and only goes back for a few months(guessing thats when I upgraded OS).

Does anyone know how to export the search history from beginning of time?

Answer (score 1):

Steps for any OS:

1. Type `about:version` in the Chrome address bar and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> (also works for Chromium, Iridium, Brave, etc).
2. Copy the path listed under **`Profile Path`** and close Chrome.
3. Navigate to the profile folder and locate the file named `History`.
4. The file is in the SQLite3 format and can be opened with any of the available [GUIs](https://www2.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ManagementTools), for example [DB Browser for SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/) which is cross-platform, open-source and actively maintained.
5. From the SQLite tables select the `urls` table to see all visited URLs. You can also use File > Export to get them as a CSV (Excel), JSON or SQL file.
6. If you are using multiple Chrome profiles then repeat 1-5 for each profile.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this when I had to migrate data from one machine to another.

Google searches in chrome are saved along with chrome history. I migrated the complete chrome history and could get the autocomplete results for my past searches.

The search history for chrome is saved in the location

`(~UserProfile)\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`

Look for a file **History** inside this folder. This is the complete chrome history (or from the time you last cleared chrome history).